# groupby working in 3 tables and i need only one table

Tags: laravel-5

le_maincategory.mc_name affected all table. I need one table using groupby option
Model

```php
public static function mainmenucategory()
{
    return DB::table('le_maincategory')
        ->join('le_addcategory', 'le_addcategory.cat_id', '=', 'le_maincategory.mc_name')
        ->join('le_add_subcategory', 'le_add_subcategory.main_cat_id', '=', 'le_maincategory.mc_name')
        ->join('le_second_category', 'le_second_category.main_cat_id', '=', 'le_maincategory.mc_name')
        ->where('le_maincategory.mc_status', '=', '1')
        ->where('le_addcategory.status', '=', '1')
        ->groupBy('le_maincategory.mc_name')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: i want to show the products like tree structure..